# Removing substituing space with a preg_replace in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

```
<a param1="false" class="param2" id="id#12" href="#1">toto</a>
```

I have made a **preg_replace** in **PHP** to remove certain params in a html text:

```
$re = "/(param1=\"false\"|class=\"param2\"|id=\"id#([^\"]+)\")/";

$text = preg_replace($re, " ", $data->text->value);
```

I obtain this **html** link:

`<a       href="#1">toto</a>`

I would like to leave only one space beetween the  **and the href**, is it possible to do that directly in the regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regular regular in the following way,

```
$re = '/(param1="false"\s+|class="param2"\s+|id="id#([^\"]+)"\s+)/';
```

You need to pass `\s+` in each of your component.

And change your `preg_replace()` function in the following way,

```
$text = preg_replace($re, "", $data->text->value);
```

Don't replace them with space, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to use all the backrefrences in your "preg_match". This is the only way you can accomplish

```
$re = "/<a.*(param1=\"false\"|class=\"param2\"|id=\"id#([^\"]+)\")/";
$text = preg_replace($re, "<a", $data->text->value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$re = "/(param1=\"false\"|class=\"param2\"|id=\"id\#([^\"]+)\")([\ ]{1,}?)/";
$text = preg_replace($re, "", $data->text->value);
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pJ3hG7/1)